# Object.defineProperty Error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-3

I have to find an equivalent code to :

```
Object.defineProperty(object, sProperty, vValue);
```

because i'm working with an old js interpreter which doesn't support ECMA Javascript5, so i'm trying to switch to this code :

```
if(vValue.get)
  object["get "+ sProperty] = vValue.get;
 if(vValue.set)
  object["set " + sProperty] = vValue.set;
```

but it doesn't work.
PS : my vValue is :
[image: vValue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `vValue` is of the form `value: x`, then

```
function myDefineProperty(object, sProperty, vValue) {
  object[sProperty] = vValue.value;
}
```

If `vValue` is a property descriptor including `get` and `set`, then you could experiment with using `__defineGetter__` and `__defineSetter__` if they are available in your environment:

```
function myDefineProperty(object, sProperty, vValue) {
  object.__defineGetter__(sProperty, vValue.get);          
  object.__defineSetter__(sProperty, vValue.set);
}
```

For a more full-featured implementation, see the polyfill at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties#Polyfill.

Comment: What is your browser/engine?

Comment: I just add object[sProperty] = {}; and it works thank you :)